# Removing history or line numbers from ZSH history file

Tags: shell, zsh

For some reason I get these odd line numbers or history numbers of some sort into my `~/.zsh_history` file like so:

```
: 1266694881:0;rake db:migrate
```

I'd rather not have to resort to regexing out the beginning, but I'd like my lines to be something like:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to solve this? I've found `setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY` but it doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: Maybe I can just remove those first 15 characters easily with regex... uhh.. any thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand everything : do you have these numbers on every lines ? Do you know what these numbers are or do you only want to remove them ?

Comment: I actually don't know what they are for, if you are using ZSH, check it out in `~/.zsh_history` I'd rather ZSH not save that portion with the history at all, my interim solution for searching history is as such `cat ~/.zsh_history | grep $1 | sed "s/...............//"` But this is ridiculous.

Comment: `grep $1 ~/.zsh_history | cut -c 16-`

Comment: I don't have any of these numbers in my zsh history. What version of zsh are you running ? what is the content of your .zshrc ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
unsetopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```

The numbers are the number of seconds since the Unix epoch of when the command began and the duration in seconds that the command ran.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that you should use the `fc` command to interact with history instead of parsing the history file. There are at least a couple of reasons for this. One is that the history file doesn't have the in-memory entries until you exit the shell, a threshold is met or you explicitly write it with the `fc -AI` command (I believe). Secondly, you can leave `EXTENDED_HISTORY` turned on and still interact with the entries without having to remove that information. If it's off, then when you do `fc -ld`, the shell uses the time that the shell started for the timestamp for commands in the history before that time. If it's off, it remembers the actual date and time (the numbers you're seeing in the file).

See `man zshbuiltins`.

List the most recent entries:

```
fc -l
```

List them without command numbers:

```
fc -ln
```

List the most recent 20 commands without command numbers:

```
fc -ln -20
```

Include a timestamp and print only the most recent command:

```
fc -lnd -1
```

Show all the commands (within the last 50) that include the string "setop" (shows `setopt` and `unsetopt`):

```
fc -l -m '*setopt*' -50
```

Comment: yah I tried this it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Does it show "extendedhistory" among others when you enter the `setopt` command without any arguments at the shell prompt?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, that solves alot of things, and it also shows incomplete lines that were never sent from ZLE, that's sort of amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `~/.zshrc`:

```shell
setopt no_extended_history no_share_history
```

Add to `~/.bashrc`, `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, etc for other shell.